# Django - get value from html select options that have been generated in a loop

Tags: html, django, loops

i have a html page where i have set up a loop to list band names on a page. I also have a select option box so users can rate bands they have seen. Problem is because each of the select options is generated in my loop i don't know how i'm going to access each rating back in my views.py file. Please help?

html code

```
{%  for band in  thursday_apex %}
<li> {{ band.band_name }}
    {{  }}
 <select name="thursday_apex">
    <option value="0">Didn't watch</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the same `name` attribute for each iterated data in for loop, to access the **value** of each `select` element you need to do it like this:

your html:

```
{%  for band in  thursday_apex %}
<li> {{ band.band_name }}
 <select name="thursday_apex_{{band.id}}">
    // options
 </select>  
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

your views.py:

```
def function(request):
    thursday_apex = YOUR_BAND_CLASS.objects.all()
    list = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for item in thursday_apex:
            select_value = request.POST.get('thursday_apex_' + str(item.id))
            if select_value:
                list.append({item.id: select_value})
    print(list)
```

now you have all the `select` values inside the variable **list**

Comment: be sure that the looped data in your html must be the same as the looped data inside the views.py

Comment: what does the following code mean?  if select_value:   Is it checking if select_vaue has a value in it? Seems like its shorthand for something

Comment: yes its checking if it exists or not